# Batch process with Scope giving: "Too many SOQL queries: 101"

Tags: batch

I wrote a batch class to avoid the "Too many SOQL" error.
Works fine in my sandbox fails verification in production.

Looking at my code below, is there something else I need to add?
I tried setting the scope to '1' thinking it would update a single record at a time to avoid any possibility of "Too many SOQL queries".
I feel there must be something I'm missing because I can use DataLoader to update 100's of Contact records, say, 4 batch records at a time, and I don't run into this error.

I'd really like some insight why this is happening and a way to code it so I avoid the limits.

Thanks again,

Kevin

Fails on this duplicate catcher plugin we use.

> FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: awduplicate2:Too many SOQL queries:
>   101

// This kicks off the batch process

```
global with sharing class ADV_MajorGiftProspect implements Schedulable
{

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch batch = new OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch(); 
        Database.executeBatch(batch, 1);   
    }

}
```

// This is the batch process

```
global class OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> 
{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        String query = 'Select contact.id, contact.Name from OpportunityContactRole WHERE Opportunity.DEPARTMENT_TYPE__C = \'Advancement\' AND Opportunity.DEPARTMENT_Sub_Type__C = \'Major Gifts\' AND Contact.Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c = false';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) 
    {
     Map<Id,Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id,Contact>();
     for(sObject s : scope)
     {
        OpportunityContactRole ocr = (OpportunityContactRole)s;
        if(!contactMap.containsKey(ocr.Contact.Id))
        {
            Contact con = new Contact(Id=ocr.Contact.Id,Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c = true);
            contactMap.put(ocr.Contact.Id,con);
        }
     }
     update contactMap.values();
}   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
    }
}
```

// This is my test for the classes

```
@isTest
private class ADV_MajorGiftProspect_TEST {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        // TO DO: implement unit test

            // Create data for testing
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name='TestAccount';
            insert a;

            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.AccountId = a.Id;
            c.lastName = 'TestLastName';
            c.Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c = false;
            insert c; 

            Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name ='Advancement test',
                        AccountID = a.ID,
                        StageName = 'Customer Won',
                        CLoseDate = Date.today(),
                        DEPARTMENT_TYPE__C = 'Advancement', 
                        DEPARTMENT_Sub_Type__C = 'Major Gifts'
                        );
            insert o;

            OpportunityContactRole ocrr = new OpportunityContactRole(OpportunityId = o.Id, ContactId = c.Id);
            insert ocrr;

            // Start the test
            test.startTest();

            OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch batch = new OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch(); 
            Database.executeBatch(batch, 1);   

            // Stop test
            test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `awduplicate2` ?

Comment: It's a duplicate record checker package we purchased called: 
Duplicate Check for Salesforce 2.0

Comment: when you say 'fails in Production' I presume this is when you attempt to deploy? Is Duplicate Check for Salesforce 2.0 also deployed in your sandbox?  Do you have a fullcopy sandbox where it is deployed and you can also then try your test class in the fullcopy sandbox?  Is this batch (and test) class the only thing you are deploying?  Sounds like a difference betw sandbox org data and prod org data

Comment: Yep, when I deploy from my sandbox.
I actually don't know if we have a fullcopy sandbox to try this on...
DupCheck is deployed on my sandbox, I do have a small record set there.
I am only deploying these three classes to production.

Comment: time to look at the debug log in detail to see where all those soql are coming from

Comment: In production, I re-verified my In-bound 'change set' and watched the verification process.  It looks like it kicks off verification of many classes other than than just mine.  My code class actually does not fail, but another one does, blocking mine from passing.  I'm curious, does any In-Bound Change Set verification run all custom code classes?

Comment: aha -- any deployment to PROD will rerun all apex testmethods, including ones for existing, already deployed classes. So, sort the problem out in PROD first to figure out which classes are failing before you do any deployment

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but my guess is that you have a triggers on Account, Contact, and/or Opportunity,  that are firing and querying the database. I'm also guessing that "awduplicate2" is one of those queries. This may or may not be the source of the problem, but this is where the error came from so I would start there.

Given that you have some code named "duplicate" in your system, I would bet money that there is a query inside a for-loop in that code - and that's the most likely source of your error.

Comment: The thing that gets me is that I can modify a lot of Contact records with Salesforce's DataLoader product, with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

If your code works in sandbox and fails in production, this means that the two environments are different. You probably have a trigger that fires in production but not in sandbox. Did you check all the triggers that you have in production?

Also, by any chance, do you have a rollup summary field on Account object that exists in production and not in sandbox? Sometimes, rollup summary fields may cause this kind of errors. For example, you update a contact, a rollup summary field changes in the parent Account, and therefore a trigger on that account fires.

Finally, the best thing to do is to read carefully the debug log. If you debug thoroughly, you should be able to detect the failing line of code and find the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm pretty sure the key to my issue is a failing test from another class method in production.  The clue to all of this was from crop1645

"aha -- any deployment to PROD will rerun all apex testmethods, including ones for existing, already deployed classes. So, sort the problem out in PROD first to figure out which classes are failing before you do any deployment –"

I found an issue with a class in production.  That's my path to peruse now.
Thanks everyone for the tips.

Kevin

Comment: As  follow-up, we uninstalled the Duplicate Check for Salesforce 2.0 package from production.  I successfully deployed my Incoming Change Set.